# How to use Get request with DTO in NestJs?

Tags: node.js, get, swagger, nestjs, dto

I am trying to write a function to handle the Get request, here is my code:

```
  @Get('/find')
  async find(@Param() testname: NameDto) {
    console.log(testname.name);
  }
```

Here is my dto:

```
export class NameDto {
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty({ required: true })
  name: string;
}
```

I am using the Swagger to test this API :
[image]
When I input a signle a , I got the following response:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "name must be a string"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

here are more input example :

[image]
[image]

They all return the same response.

Then, I change the find function like this with @Query:

```
  @Get('/find')
  async find(@Query() testname: NameDto) {
    console.log(testname.name);
  }
```

here is my input :
[image]
I can have the 200-ok response.
Here is another example:
[image]
I enter 1 as the input, and I still can get the 200 response. The dto is not working as expected.

Am I missing something?
Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

you are sending nothing in param
you can read in [Nestjs document](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object)
try this one:

```js
@Get('/find/:testname')
  async find(@Param('testname') testname: NameDto) {
    console.log(testname.name);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using query parameters for the url, so you do need to use `@Query()`. Query parameters will **always** come in as strings, because that's how express and fastify work. You can enable `transform: true` and [`{transformOptions: { enableImplicitConverion: true } }`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/interfaces/external/class-transform-options.interface.ts#L47) in the `ValidationPipe`'s options and get numbers to show up as actual numbers.

Comment: Hi Jay, I change my code to this : @Get('/find')   @UsePipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true },
    }),
  )
  async find(@Query() testname: NameDto) {
    console.log(testname.name);
  }  the dto still not work, there is no different between enter a and 1

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this it's works for me:

```
//find-one.dto.ts

import { IsNotEmpty, IsUUID } from 'class-validator';

export class FindOneParams {
  @IsUUID()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  uuid: string;
}
```

```
//controller.ts

@Get(':uuid')
find(@Param() { uuid }: FindOneParams) {
    return this.yourService.find(uuid);
  }
```

```
//service.ts

find = (uuid: string): Promise<yourType> => ...
```